# Facing issues - Olingo OData 4.0 Java Library integration in SpringBoot app

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, odata, olingo

I integrated Olingo OData 4.0 Java Library with normal Maven project and was able to get the results for a sample read application. I did use hibernate to connect to my own PostgreSQL data source and was able to get the results there as well.

But I am not able to get the results when I followed the same steps for a spring boot application.

I tried the following approaches :

1. In RestController class, I provided a request mapping and in one of the class methods, implemented following code.
2. Created a separate Servlet file and in the service method, again called below code.

I've also made sure that the EDMprovider and processor files have necessary changes. But still no luck.

Can someone please guide me to integrate OData 4.0 Java Library with SpringBoot 2.0?

```
OData odata = OData.newInstance();
ServiceMetadata edm = odata.createServiceMetadata(new DemoEdmProvider(), new ArrayList<EdmxReference>());
  ODataHttpHandler handler = odata.createHandler(edm);
  handler.register(new DemoEntityCollectionProcessor());
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?